# Promise not getting resolved while copying all files from source to destination directory. How can do this using promises?

Tags: javascript, nodes

I am trying to copy all files from source to destination by using NodeJs's **fs** module's read/write stream.

Comment: Please provide us some code what have you done so far.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```
const fs = require('fs');
const sourceDirPath = process.argv[2];
const DestinationDirPath = process.argv[3];

const checkInputPaths = ()=>{
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const message = 'please provide source and destination dir path';
    if (!(sourceDirPath && DestinationDirPath)) {
      console.log(message);
      return reject(message);
    }

    return resolve();
  }); //end of promise

};

const readDirFiles = (files)=> {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    return fs.readdir(sourceDirPath, function(err, files) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }

      return resolve(files);
    });
  });
};

const writeLog = (file, log, fileIndex)=> {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let dataToAppend = '';
    if (fileIndex == 0) {
      dataToAppend += `${log} \n${fileIndex + 1}. Copied file ${file}.`;
    } else {
      dataToAppend = `\n${fileIndex + 1}. Copied file ${file}.`;
    }

    return fs.appendFile(DestinationDirPath + '/log.txt', dataToAppend, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`Error while appending to file: ${file}`);
        return resolve();
      }

      console.log(`The file: ${file} was appended to log file!`);
      return resolve();
    });
  });
};

const writeFileToDir = (files, log, fileIndex)=> {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (!fileIndex) {
      fileIndex = 0;
    }
    const file = files[fileIndex];

    return fs.copyFile(`${sourceDirPath + file}`, `${DestinationDirPath + file}`, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`Error while copying file: ${file} from ${sourceDirPath} to ${DestinationDirPath}`);
        return (++fileIndex < files.length) ? writeFileToDir(files, log, fileIndex) : resolve();
      }
      return writeLog(file, log, fileIndex, log).then(()=>{
        return (++fileIndex < files.length) ? writeFileToDir(files, log, fileIndex) : resolve();
      });
    });
  });
};

const copyDir = ()=> {
  console.log('Started disctory copying process.......');
  const log = `:: Files copying from ${sourceDirPath} to ${DestinationDirPath}`;
  return readDirFiles().then((files)=>{
    return writeFileToDir(files, log).then(()=>{
      console.log(`All files copied from ${sourceDirPath} to ${DestinationDirPath} successfully`);
      return Promise.resolve();
    }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log(`Error while copying files from source to destination : ${err}`);
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
  }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(`Error while copying files from source to destination : ${err}`);
    return Promise.reject(err);
  });
};


copyDir();
```